# Using NonNegative setting in Matlab odeset()

Tags: matlab, ode

I'm trying to solve some ODEs in MatLab and seeing as the variables in the equations are populations they need to be constrained to being positive. So I tried using odeset() before calling the equation solver to make them non-negative but on plotting the values afterwards they are actually negative at times (in the code below it is the magenta line). What am I doing wrong?

Here's some code:

```
%Lots of variables
includeJ=1;
cullLIRate=1/2000;
cullDIRate=1/2000;
N = 16800;
beta = 2e-7;
delta = 0.5;
gamma = 1/50;
sigma = 1/400;
mu = 1/365;
maxTime = 30*365;
kappa = N;
gR = 0.05;
mJ = 1/3650;
initJPerAdult = 10;
numInitE = 1000;
TSpan = [0,maxTime];

initState = [N-numInitE,numInitE,0,0,0,initJPerAdult*N];

%IMPORTANT BIT HERE
options = odeset('NonNegative', 1:6)
scirSoln = ode45(@equation,TSpan,initState,[],beta,delta,gamma,sigma,mu,kappa,gR,mJ,cullLIRate,cullDIRate,includeJ);

scirVals = deval(scirSoln,timeToPlot);
plot(timeToPlot,scirVals(1,:));
hold on;
plot(timeToPlot,scirVals(3,:),'k');
plot(timeToPlot,scirVals(4,:),'g');
plot(timeToPlot,scirVals(6,:),'m');

timeToPlot = [0:max(TSpan)/1000:max(TSpan)];
```

The code for equation(...) is:

```
function retVal = equation(t,y,beta,delta,gamma,sigma,mu,kappa,gR,mJ,cullLIRate,cullDIRate,includeJ)
retVal = zeros(6,1);

S = y(1);
E = y(2);
LI = y(3);
DI = y(4);
R = y(5);
J = y(6);

retVal(1)= mJ * J - beta * S * (delta * LI + DI);
retVal(2) = beta * S * (delta * LI + DI) - gamma * E;
retVal(3) = gamma * E - (cullLIRate + sigma) * LI;
retVal(4) = sigma * LI - (mu + cullDIRate) * DI;
retVal(5) = mu * DI + cullLIRate* LI + cullDIRate * DI;
retVal(6) = gR * S * (1 - S / kappa) - mJ * J;

end
```

Comment: You are not passing your defined odeset (options variable) to the ODE45 - solver. The syntax for the ODE45 is:

    [T,Y] = ODE45(ODEFUN,TSPAN,Y0,OPTIONS,P1,P2...)

Try that and get back to me if you still have a problem and I'll take a closer look.

Comment: Thanks that worked! Adapting code from another source and didn't realise... If you put this as an answer I'll happily accept and give you some credit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing your defined odeset (options variable) to the ODE45 - solver.

The syntax for the ODE45 is: [T,Y] = ODE45(ODEFUN,TSPAN,Y0,OPTIONS,P1,P2...)

Glad it worked! :)